How can I create hexadecimal map files?
I create maps like this, where each tile's data is represented in hexadecimal format:
01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 
01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 
01 00 00 00 B0 00 00 FF 00 00 00 01
01 00 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01
01 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 01
01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01

While I can create them with any text editor, it's incredibly inefficient (It takes too much effort and time), So is there tool to create these map files?
I found Tiled, but idk how to create these map files with it, or even if it's possible at all.
NOTE: I want a tool that allows me to choose the value I want for the tile.

You could create a bitmap with 16 colours in MS paint and write a script that would convert to and from your own format? Or do the same with Tiled..?

I just had a quick look at the Tiled website, and found that it supports custom output plugins: https://doc.mapeditor.org/en/stable/manual/python/#example-export-plugin

Is this your own input format, or for an existing game?

@Vaillancourt
I still write it in a text editor, so it's inefficient too, and there's also a high chance I'll make a mistake in converting, so I'll need to compare the script with the bitmap (It will be a big problem since I will be making large maps).

The link from Adam even has an almost fully equal example for the format that you want in the end. All you have to do is remove the , and use hexadecimal instead of the ints.

@HolyBlackCat
This is just a simple example to illustrate what I need.

@Zibelas
Is there a more efficient way? (considering I'll create large maps)

What do you mean with efficient? Using an editor seems efficient for me. And the link tells you how you can export to your custom format.

"This is just a simple example to illustrate what I need." This doesn't answer my question though. (If this is your own game's format, I'd recommend changing it to something Tiled supports.)

@Zibelas
I mean save effort and time, convert each decimal to hexadecimal will require too much effort and time.

@HolyBlackCat
I think you didn't understand me completely (or I didn't understand you completely), I make game engine reads map files in hexadecimal format, and I need tool to export/create hexadecimal map files to save effort and time.

How is it that much effort to convert an int to hexa decimal? Thats one function call in the export script

@Zibelas
How do I do this?

You typically write a script that converts from a format that is easy to edit (e.g. a bitmap in your case) to the hex format you're after, which is easy to use by your game/engine. Once the script is written and works correctly, you don't need to edit it, you edit your map in MS paint, or tiled (where you can use a plugin as it's been mentioned), and and run the script on that input file. You no longer need to edit your script until your format changes.

Take the script from the link that Adam posted, look up the place where it writes the id (hint: something like str(tileLayer.cellAt(x, y).tile().id()) is a good candidate), use google to find pythons converting function from int to hex (like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269827/how-to-convert-an-int-to-a-hex-string), copy the script to the directory and be done.
